# システムの統合について

Tags: apache, postgresql, tomcat, データベース設計, database

現在、同じシステムが複数の別々のサイトとして稼働しています。

仕組みは**apache+tomcat+postgres**のwebサービスです。

この複数のサイトを1つのサイトに統合することになった場合に
複数のデータを同じDBにひとまとめにするとして、
問題の一つとして**ログテーブルのプライマリーキー(連番)が重複してしまう**ことが考えられます

プライマリーキーが他のテーブルのカラムにも紐づいたりして、作業量としてかなり重く、
データベース構成も複雑なためリスクの高い対応になってしまいます。

そこで、既存のテーブル構成をあまり変えずに、データを統合するいい方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: すぐに思いつくのは統合前システムごとにスキーマを分けるか、統合前のシステムを示す識別子を格納するカラムを追加して複合主キーとする方法ですが、「一つのサイトに統合する」主眼が何なのか、どのくらいのデータ量やテーブルの数があるのか等で方針が変わってくると思います。これまでにどのような方法を検討して、それらの方法ではどういう問題が発生すると考えているのか、統合にあたって絶対に外せない条件は何なのか、などといったあたりをもう少し詳細にしていただけると良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

「複数のサイトを1つのサイトに統合」がただ単に「一つのサーバで複数サイトを運営したい」という話であればDBの統合は不要です。今あるDBを単純に移行すればよいでしょう。

逆に、DBの統合をするために「複数のサイトを1つのサイトに統合」するのであれば、システム全体の要件ありきの話なので、誰にも答えられない質問です。例としてあげられている「ログテーブル」にしても、それは一つにしなければならないのか複数のままで良いのかは要件次第です。